# TrueType font library for Python 3

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, truetype

I have a font name in a list. And I want to copy a font file (.ttf, .otf) of these fonts from Windows font directory to specified directory. And some of the font name are in localized form (i.e. I can't use windows registry to figure out the font name)

I found several Python solution, but I can't find any that run on python 3 and windows.

Are there any library I can use (since speed is not important, I'd be okay for a library that can read ttf/otf metadata.

Comment: Post one or two solutions you found that works in Python 2.

Comment: fontTools and TTFQuery. Also fontconfig works on Linux.

Comment: TTFQuery depends on FontTools-TTX, so it would make no sense in porting it to Python 3 at this point. In http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2627144&group_id=29196&atid=395372 there is a discussion about porting FontTools-TTX to Python 3, and there is a  big patch too that you could try applying yourself. But, the easiest solution is to use Python 2, can't you do that ?

Comment: It also depends on other 3.0 only library. Though if no solution appear, i'd perhaps just run 2.7 code in another process.

Comment: Did you try applying the patch attached in the link mentioned ? That could be a solution for you.

Comment: Try FontTools and ttfquery for Python 3 from http://vpython.org/contents/download_linux.html (FontModulesPython3.zip). In my experience they don't work too well but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If you found python2 solutions, you can convert them to python3 with [2to3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html)

Comment: I tried it with fontTool, and it doesn't work with fontTools. Or at least I can't make it work. If you could point me to converted solution, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `python-fontbro` library (I'm the author of this lib) for retrieving font names metadata and much more very easily:

**Installation:**

```bash
pip install python-fontbro
```

**Usage:**

```py
from fontbro import Font

with Font("fonts/MyFont.ttf") as font:
    names = font.get_names()

print(names) # -> dict containing all the name records
```

**Documentation**

Here there is the list of all available methods:

https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/python-fontbro#methods